# Installing Office 97 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I've been trying to install Office 97 in a Windows 7 Pro 64 bits PC without luck: when I run the setup file from a CD, a USB stick or after copying all the files to the hard drive, either as a normal user or as an administrator, I get a message saying something like (*) "This version is not compatible with the Windows version you are using.... Check to see if you need a x86 (32 bits) or x64 (64 bits) of the program ..." Same thing happens if I run it in "compatibility mode" selecting Windows XP or older OS. So *it seems* that it cannot use it in a 64 bits OS.

However, if I copy all the files from the CD to a folder in harddisk C and I run from there either Excel.exe or Powerpoint.exe, they work fine. If I run Winword.exe, I first get a message in a window saying something like (*)"Windows configuration registry informs that one or several of the necessary files are damaged or not found. You can correct this problem running Word's setup program". After I click the "accept"button or close that window, Word 97 starts and works OK (at least all the features I use).

[image]

I have already Office 2010 installed in the same PC, and I would like to keep it (as I need it for dealing with docx and xlsx files, but for most of my work, I can do it better and faster with Office 97, as I have been working with itfor ages.

Is there a way to either:
a) Do a normal installation that works and that doesn't ruin my Office 2010, or
b) Get rid of the window that appears everytime before Word 97 starts with that useless warning? (Maybe a batch file, a script or a simple auto-it file?)

(*) they are non-English version of Windows 7 and Office 97, so the messages are not in English. I have translated as best as I am able. Excuse me if there are errors.

Comment: Have you tried to right-click the installation executable and set its compatibility to an older version such as Windows 98 or 95?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: Thanks for the info. I have servipack 1, can't find servipacks 2 or 3, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. As for Outlook 97, I have never used it (nor  have any intention)

Comment: @harrymc: Yes, I have tried settting the compatibility to all the possibilities from Wp5 to Windows XP SP3, without success :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the root of your problem is that Office 97 has a 16 bit installer stub. 64 bit versions of windows don't have NTVDM (needed to run 16 bit software), so I suspect a windows VM that's 32 bit *might* be the best option. There *might* be a way to run this in a 64 bit version by 'skipping' the stub - someone came across [the same issue in wine](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=23767) ([based off a solution for reactos](https://reactos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=10988)) and managed to install it, and fundamentally it is the same problem.

> In the specific case of Word 97, there is on the CD a 32-bit installer called ACMSETUP.EXE, and a related program called WORD97.STF. Here is their suggestion:
>
> "Many Microsoft setup programs from 95 to 97 have a 16-bit loader stub. Instead of running this file, locate and run the 32-bit ACMSETUP instead.... "
>
> "When running the ACMSETUP pass the "/T" parameter followed by the name of the included ".STF" file. (Or alternatively rename the .STF file to ACMSETUP.STF)."

I also suspect if this works, office 97 is so old it might not be detected/detect a newer install (even if in my experience, office dosen't like concurrent versions) and it might 'just work'. I'd check but I don't really think I kept my office 97 media to try this.

Comment: Re keeping multiple versions of Office on one PC: best practice is to install the oldest version first, install any service packs it needs, then install later versions the same way, in order. They may still argue with one another, but will generally behave. I've got a VM with everything from Office 97 through 2003.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: On windows 7 my experience is that it Excel an Powerpoint run withouut installation and without problems - as for Word 97 (from the Office 97 bundle, not from a standalone disk), it also runs OK after displaying the warning message I mentioned in the queestion

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit of effort, but there is a way to get NVTDM working on Windows 7 x64 by compiling and installing this software:  https://github.com/leecher1337/ntvdmx64
Once you install that, you will be able to run x16 executables the same way windows runs x32 software on a x64 system.

Comment: I have exactly the same setup of Win 7 Pro 64bit, and Office 2010. I also happened to be doing a disc image reinstall, so decided to try installing my old Word 97 disc, (not Office  97). Installed and functioned fine, but the window warning you are accepting is reconfiguring the registry. When I switch to Word 2010, that then reconfigures back again. Not an ideal setup. The issue is clearly the running of two versions of Word/Office on the same system. Both are trying to share the same registry settings. Can't see how you can resolve this other than creating a portable version of Word 97.

Comment: Thank you for your answwer. Unfortunately, the solution you offer is too complex from my limited computer knowledge

Comment: @Sark: Thank you for the information. The idea of being reconfiguring the registry all the time really scares me. I'll try to find or create a portable version of Word 97 then